# If statement when echoing html

Tags: php, html

So I'm trying to generate select values with a loop. The issue here is that I can't use an if statement. I could set pieces of string together with a number of if statements, but that seems like an odd solution.

```
<select name="test">
              <option disabled selected> -- Select an industry -- </option>
              <?php 
                $numberOfIndustries = count($industryOptions); //industryOptions is an array
                for($i = 0; $i <= $numberOfIndustries; $i++) {
                  echo "<option" . if (isset($_POST['test']) == true && $_POST['test'] == $industryOptions[$i]) { .  "selected='true'" . }; . "value=" . $industryOptions[$i] . ">" . $industryOptions[$i] . "</option>";
                }
              ?> 
</select>
```

Comment: So what is your question then? How you can code this in a better way?

Comment: My question was "is there something I can use to solve this in a better way?", and I got ternary operator as an answer, which is exactly what I needed. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the `.` (dot) to concat `IF` clause - only strings. Instead, you can use the [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary).

So your `echo` call should look as follows:

```
echo "<option " . 
     (isset($_POST['test']) && ($_POST['test'] == $industryOptions[$i]) ? "selected='true' " : ""). 
     "value=" . $industryOptions[$i] . ">" . $industryOptions[$i] . "</option>";
```

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Just echo separately instead of creating one huge statement that is impossible to read.

```
<?php 
    $numberOfIndustries = count($industryOptions); //industryOptions is an array
    for($i = 0; $i <= $numberOfIndustries; $i++) {
        echo "<option";
        if (isset($_POST['test']) == true && $_POST['test'] == $industryOptions[$i]) {
            echo " selected='true'";
        }
        echo " value=" . $industryOptions[$i] . ">" . $industryOptions[$i] . "</option>";
    }
?>
```

However, if you really want to use a one line statement there is a thing called `conditional ternary operator` which allows you to do what you want to do.

```
<?php 
    $numberOfIndustries = count($industryOptions); //industryOptions is an array
    for($i = 0; $i <= $numberOfIndustries; $i++) {
        echo "<option" . ((isset($_POST['test']) == true && $_POST['test'] == $industryOptions[$i]) ? "selected='true'" : "") . "value=" . $industryOptions[$i] . ">" . $industryOptions[$i] . "</option>";
    }
?>
```